# reducebykey followed by foreachpartition in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I understand in spark that reducebykey will reduce first locally on each partition and then do the shuffle. However, if I have reducebyKey followed by a action foreachpartition , will reducebykey still perform a global wide reduce or it will limit the reduce on to each partition level and won't do shuffle among different partition?

Answer (score 1):

The subsequent action has no impact on the `reduceByKey` at all. No matter what it is `reduceByKey` (or any other similar method) will shuffle the data as usual.